# Convert PSD while keeping layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I have a couple of PSD files that I need to convert into PNG but I need to keep the layers separate. I don't have Photoshop and was wondering if it was possible to do this

[click here for the files if anyone who has Photoshop could do this for me. thanks!](http://bit.ly/hudfiles)

Comment: Hi! What software do you use if you're not using Photoshop? Also, do you mean you want to be able to edit the layers in a PNG or so you want to have each layers saved as a PNG? You can't have layers in a PNG, it's a "flat" file.

Comment: [Fireworks PNGs](https://www.adobe.com/support/fireworks/export/fw_export_vs_sav/fw_export_vs_sav02.html) can have layers and other data but that - as far as I'm aware - is the only situation and application in which you can have layers in a PNG file. And I'm not sure how you would export that from PS. Probably you would have to export the layers as files and import individually in Fireworks.

Comment: I downloaded the files off of the internet as PSD and didn't create them. I want to have each layer saved as a separate PNG or other image file.

Answer (score 2):

### Converting the Layers Using GIMP

Probably the best way of doing this is by installing and using [**GIMP**](https://www.gimp.org/).

After installing open it up (may take a while to load).

[image: Start]

You can then drag and drop your **.PSD** file straight into the canvas and it should open in the layers panel.

[image: Step2]

Similar to Photoshop, if you're familiar with the layout, there is a panel on the right where you can view the layers of the document.

**NOTE:** Depending on the complexity of the Photoshop file, there may be some things that you will not be able to view properly in GIMP, in my case the file is very basic so it is not an issue.

[image: Step2a]

Now there are 2 ways you can export the layers to **.PNG**s, the first is more tedious, however the second is slightly more complex and involves installing a GIMP plugin, I'll cover both.

---

### Manually Exporting the Layers

Only make visible the layers you wish to export as a **.PNG**, and go to `File`>`Export`. In my case here it is the first layer and the white background, so I will make sure that they are the only ones visible.

[image: Step3]

Locate where you want to save your layers and type in the name of your layer+the file extension, in this case it will be called 'Layer1.png'

[image: Step4]

Hit <kbd>Export</kbd> and then you can repeat the process for the other layers (said it would be tedious!)

Alternatively you have the option of...

---

### Using a Plug-in Script to Export the Layers

It seems the best plugin is a script by **khalim19** found [**here**](https://github.com/khalim19/gimp-plugin-export-layers).

Follow the instructions on the GitHub page on how to install it.

Once it's installed the process is largely the same as the previous method, although there are some changes.

Firstly, make sure all of the layers that you want to export are visible.

[image: Step2a]

Then, with the plug-in installed (you will need to restart GIMP if you haven't done so in order for it to be visible), go `File`>`Export as Layers`.

[image: Step5]

Similar to before, navigate to the place where you want the layers to be saved. Select the file type and play about with the settings below it if needed (they're fairly self explanatory).

[image: Step6]

Hit <kbd>Export Layers</kbd> and you'll be brought to another dialogue box. The default settings work okay so you can leave them as they are, hit <kbd>Export</kbd>.

[image: Final Box1]

And you're done! The layers will export out as individual **.PNG** files to your chosen location.

[image: Ta Da!]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

From the way the question was posed I gather this is a one-time situation. If so, you have a few options:

1. Give the files to a friend and have your friend do this for you if the contents are not confidential
2. Download a trial version of Photoshop CC and save the layers as separate files
3. Download the open source GIMP which will open the PSD file, then you can save the layers

I am assuming that PNG was used as an example format. It may be relevant if the layer had transparency; otherwise you may want to save them as TIFF files and then you can convert them to any format you like in the future.

Comment: I don't know much about image formats and such but I need something that can support transparency. (I will be using it to make a movie in fusion 8)

Comment: You may follow the instructions in the second answer and save your layers as separate files in PNG or PSD format, either will support transparency. Your application, fusion, may tell you what format files it will accept.

Answer (score -2):

In photoshop Go to **File menu > Scripts > Export Layers to File**